# c++ program gives an error" the value of 'i' is not initiated"

Tags: c++, visual-c++

this code gives an error "i" is not initiated, can anybody help it out ?
the program complies easily. and at the time of running, every switch case works but 2.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

const int m=50;
class ITEMS
{
    int itemCode[m];
    float itemPrice[m];
    int count;
public:
    void CNT(void)
    {
        count=0;
    }
    void getItem(void);
    void displaySum(void);
    void remove(void);
    void displayItems(void);
};
```

functions used.

```
void ITEMS :: getItem (void)
{
    cout<<"entr itm cod";
    cin>> itemCode[count];
    cout<<"entr itm cost";
    cin>> itemPrice[count];
    count++;
}
```

the problem is here. this function"displaySum (void)" must give an output by summing the prices of all the items

```
void ITEMS ::displaySum (void)
{
    float sum =0;
    for (int i; i<count;i++)
        sum+=itemPrice[i];
    cout<<"\n total value"<< sum<<endl;
}
void ITEMS ::remove (void)
{
    int a;
    cout<< "entr itm cod";
    cin>> a;
for(int i=0; i<count;i++)
    if (itemCode[i] == a)
        itemPrice[i]=0;
}
void ITEMS :: displayItems(void)
{
    cout<< "\n Code price\n";
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        cout<<"\n" << itemCode[i];
        cout<<"  " << itemPrice[i];
    }
    cout<< endl;
}
```

main function. this is here i called all the above functions. using the main function.

```
int main()
{
    ITEMS order;
    order.CNT();
    int x;
    do
    {
        cout<< "select any opt"
            <<"\n 1. add"
            <<"\n 2. display total valu"
            <<"\n 3. delete an item"
            <<"\n 4. display all"
            <<"\n 5. quit?
            <<"\n number ?";
        cin>> x;

        switch(x)
        {
        case 1: order.getItem(); break;
        case 2: order.displaySum(); break;
        case 3: order.remove(); break;
        case 4: order.displayItems(); break;
        case 5: break;
        default: cout<< "try again";
        }
    }while(x!=5);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In `displaySum` you have:

```
for (int i; i<count;i++)
    sum+=itemPrice[i];
```

`i` is not initialized here.  That's probably not what you want.

Also, make sure you pay attention to what your compiler tells you.  If you are using gcc, for example, you can use the options "-Wall -Werror" which generates warnings for common programming mistakes, and reports them as errors.  IMO this is good practice as it forces you to at least look at that spot to see if you actually made a programming error.

I don't know which compiler you're using, but I don't know of a single one that does not provide *at least* a line number when printing warnings.  Use the resources available to you.  The compiler almost certainly told you exactly what was wrong and where the error occured.  While the expression you used is legal, it is certainly an error.

Comment: what could be the possible solution ?

Comment: Use `int i = 0;` instead, as you have elsewhere.

Comment: @jeet.mg: Similar to what you are doing in other places, `for (int i = 0; ....)`.

Answer (score 4):

```
int i;
```

does not initialize the local variable, make an experiment and print it, you will see it is filled with previous stack junk. so it probably wont satisfy the for(;;) condition and just never enter the loop

use

```
int i = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

In `displaySum` you are not initializing variable `i`, so it contains a garbage value and your loop will behave unpredictably.